# Trigger Google App Scripts Every time I open an existing or create a new Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to trigger google app scripts to automatically create an alert every time a existing or new Google spreadsheet is created

Is this possible?

Here is my current code which I am trying to trigger for every spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Spreadsheet opened!');
}
```

Comment: About your showing script, your script works fine when you run the script? Because I thought that the method of "setSelectionBackground" is not included in Class Sheet. And, can I ask you about the detail of `add branding color palettes to the text and background formatting toolbar at the top of the Spreadsheet`? First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue and your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I have updated my question to be easier to understand.  The root of my question is how to trigger a Google App Script function every time I create a new google sheet, or open an existing google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `open an existing google sheet`, in this case, OnOpen trigger can be used. But, I cannot imagine `I create a new google sheet`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `I create a new google sheet`? For example, `a new google sheet` is to insert a new sheet in the Google Spreadsheet? Or, `a new google sheet` is to create a new Google Spreadsheet? And, how will you do them?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I mean `a new google sheet is to create a new Google Spreadsheet`. When I go to sheets.google.com and click the + to create a blank spreadsheet, I want the Google App Script to trigger.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `When I go to sheets.google.com and click the + to create a blank spreadsheet, I want the Google App Script to trigger`, how about checking [Changes of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes)? If that was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: A little out of context - Could you elaborate on what type of alert you want to create and what will it display and the purpose? Based on the use case, may be we can suggest other solutions.